# How can a parent class's method access an subclass's overridden variable?

Tags: php, subclassing, overriding

If I have a subclass that is overriding a protected variable, and the parent class has the function to do stuff with that variable, how do I get that function to use the value it is overridden with?

```
class Superclass {
    protected $map;

    public function echoMap()
    {
        foreach ($this->map as $key=>value)
        {
            echo "$key:$value";
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
class Subclass extends Superclass {
    protected $map = array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2);
}
```

and when I run the following

```
$subclass = new Subclass();
$subclass->echoMap();
```

I would expect it to return

```
a:1
b:2
```

but `$this->map` is empty in the parent class. What should I do instead to get the behavior I want?

---

Edit:
There was a bug in the constructors, not in the example posted above. It works as expected.

Comment: There's something else going on you are not telling us. The example you gave works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does work the way you describe. The only thing I can see is in your example, Subclass does not extend Superclass. I assume this is a mistake in your example only. Check to make sure all classes actually do extend the correct class, and check to make sure you have no typos in variable names.

See http://codepad.viper-7.com/kDrbIh for an example of it working.

Comment: If forgetting to inherit was the problem then he would receive a `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Subclass::echoMap` error.

Comment: @webbiedave right, hence, "I assume this is a mistake in your example only"

Answer (score 0):

Even though it looks to be just a typo (not extending the super class), you should try initializing your variables in the constructor of both classes.

`function __construct() {
// initialize protected values
    }`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with initializing them at declaration. Plus, if he overrides the constructor as you suggest, the parent class constructor won't be called automatically. He'd have to mindful to call `parent::__construct();`

Comment: I actually was initializing them in the constructor in my application, but after that I was overwriting it with a default value (oops)

Comment: @webbiedave if php acts as how Java does, the default constructor of the superclass SHOULD be called automatically http://leepoint.net/notes-java/oop/constructors/constructor.html although i'm unaware if PHP OOP works the same way

Comment: @K2xL: In PHP, the constructor is fully overridden. You must explicitly call the parent constructor.